# Issue with "rubber-band" scrolling in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

On my webpage, I have an element $('.detailViewHandle') that adjusts its position based on the window's scroll position.  I'm running into issues because of elastic scrolling (which I've also seen referred to as 'rubber-band' scrolling); if the user scrolls very quickly beyond the limits of the page, the positioning of the element gets thrown off.  I tried to account for when the user scrolls past the limits of the page by checking the following conditions:

```
$(window).scrollTop() > 0

$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(document).height()
```

Here's the complete code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var offset = 332;
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
  if(scrollTop > 0 && scrollBottom < $(document).height()){
      $('.detailViewHandle').css('top', $(window).height()-$(window).scrollTop()-$('.projectOverviewPhoto').height()+$('.detailViewHandle').height()/2-offset);
  }
});
```

Is there a way to completely disable elastic scrolling in Chrome on OSX?  I don't seem to have this issue in Firefox.

I also can't set overflow:hidden for the body and html (which I've seen in other responses) because I require that the overflow is visible for part of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being quite a simple fix.  It turns out that there's some lag with the scrolling, so the scrollTop might jump from 150 to 0.  That left my div in the wrong position on the page.  By just setting the conditional to respond to when the scrollTop is >= 0, I was able to fix the issue.

```
if(scrollTop >= 0 && scrollBottom <= $(document).height()){
```